# matplotlib derivative sign in a raw string title

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, plot, latex

I need to output correct label for my graph in `matplotlib`.

I have a function `f(x)`. It's derivative is `f'(x)`. I want to plot `f'(x)` with `matplotlib` using python. So I have lists of `x` and `f'(x)` values `x_to_plot` and `f_derivative_to_plot`.

So I write escaping single quote:

```
plt.plot(x_to_plot, f_derivative_to_plot, label='$f\'$')
```

which displays right label.

Next I have `f'(\beta)`. `\beta` is supposed to be greek beta symbol. I have to use raw string for label variable, so I write:

```
plt.plot(..., ..., label=r'$f\'(\beta)$')
```

But instead of normal `f` derivative I get some messed `" ' "` symbol after `f`.

Comment: Have you tried just entering the β symbol in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since your string label contains `'` character, you can use `""` to define the string. This let you remove `\` before `'`
- You can place `r` before the string, in order to specify it is a *raw string literals*. This let you use only a single `\` for special characters, like `\beta`

That been said, you could use something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
f = np.sin(x)
df = np.diff(f)/np.diff(x)
df = np.append(df, 2*df[-1] - df[-2])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, f, label = r"$f$")
ax.plot(x, df, label = r"$f'(\beta)$")

ax.legend(frameon = True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The first part of this answer worked well.